# Stop program running at startup in Linux

Tags: linux, startup, shutdown, boot

How do I stop a program running at startup in Linux. I want to remove some apps from startup to allow them to be managed by `supervisord` e.g apache2

Comment: That's exactly why I didn't tag it... I'm looking for all the variations as I work with quite a few different distros.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Depending on your distro use the chkconfig or update-rc.d tool to enable/disable system services.

On a redhat/suse/mandrake style system:

```
sudo chkconfig apache2 off
```

On Debian:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f apache2 remove
```

Checkout their man pages for more info.

Comment: Why do you need -f (I assume it's force) on Debian based distros?

Comment: There are two sets of files in play here.  You've got the actual init script in /etc/init.d/ and you have the links to it in your runlevel directory /etc/rcrunlevel.d/.  These guys point to the script in /etc/init.d/

If you don't use -f update-rd.d will fail UNLESS the script in /etc/init.d/ is already deleted.

If you do use -f update-rc.d will properly delete the link files regardless of whether or not the /etc/init.d/ script is deleted.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense, I'd forgotten that the runlevel scripts were just links to the init scripts. Thanks for the extra explanation.

Answer (score 7):

If you are dealing with a modern Ubuntu system and a few other distros you may have to deal with a combination of traditional init scripts and upstart scripts.  Managing init scripts is covered by other answers.  The following is one way to stop an upstart service from starting on boot:

```
# mv /etc/init/servicename.conf /etc/init/servicename.conf.disabled
```

The problem with this method is that it does not allow you to start the service using:

```
# service start servicename
```

An alternative to this is to open the `servicename.conf` file in your favorite editor and comment out any lines that start with:

```
start on
```

That is, change this to

```
#start on ...
```

where the "..." is whatever was after "start on" previously.  This way, when you want to re-enable it, you don't have to remember what the "start on" parameters were.

Finally, if you have a new version of upstart you can simply add the word "manual" to the end of the configuration file.  You can do this directly from the shell:

```
# echo "manual" >> /etc/init/servicename.conf
```

This will cause upstart to ignore any "start on" phrases earlier in the file.

Answer (score 7):

To list all the startup services

```
    systemctl
```

To stop a service from running on start up

```
    sudo systemctl disable servicename
```

For instance if we need to stop running ssh server at startup

```
    sudo systemctl disable sshd.service
```

We can enable this again using

```
    sudo systemctl enable sshd.service
```

Almost every linux distributions use systemd for bootstrapping startup services. So above commands work for most of the distros.

Comment: Welcome to U&L, and thank you for your contribution! I'd like to point out that this question is about eight years old now, so the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27/117549) was correct for the time. Using systemctl may be correct *now*, but it's correct for a *different question*.

Comment: @Prince thanks for the detailed explanations. It helped me to understand how the boot startup works in my Xubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

On recent Fedora and Future RHEL systems

```
systemctl disable httpd.service
```

will disable the httpd service

Comment: Thanks! I had tried many methods, but this `systmctl` command worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 10.04 you can control some startup programs from the GUI.

<kbd>System</kbd>→<kbd>Preferences</kbd>→<kbd>Startup Applications</kbd>

[image: Startup Applications Preferences]

Comment: Original image is no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

Slackware and Arch linux have similar methods of stopping/starting processes at boot, different than the Ubuntu and Redhat-style examples given above.

In both Slackware and Arch linuxes, sh scripts exist in directory `/etc/rc.d`, typically one script per daemon, or one script per subsystem.

For example, Slackware starts the Apache web server with a script `/etc/rc.d/rc.httpd`, called at the appropriate time during system startup with an argument of "start".  Arch linux has differently-named scripts, but the same sort of thing goes on.

To keep some process from starting during system boot, on Slackware, you just make the appropriate script in /etc/rc.d not executable. To keep Apache from starting at the next boot:

```
chmod -x /etc/rc.d/rc.httpd
```

To stop an Apache that got started at boot:  `/etc/rc.d/rc.httpd  stop`  You'll need to be root.

Arch is a bit more complex.  The file /etc/rc.conf, a shell script, has an array DAEMONS. To keep Apache from starting at boot, you'd change this line in /etc/rc.conf:

```
DAEMONS=(hal syslog-ng network netfs crond alsa sshd httpd ntpd postgresql)
```

To this line:

```
DAEMONS=(hal syslog-ng network netfs crond alsa sshd ntpd postgresql)
```

To stop an already executing apache, you'd execute `/etc/rc.d/httpd stop` as root.

Answer (score 0):

**IN KALI LINUX**

1.Search **TWEAKS** in search box

2.In tweaks **startup programs** you see

3.Click **remove** to stop startup applications when logon

Answer (score -2):

1. Tap <kbd>Super</kbd> Key on your keyboard.
2. Search for 'Startup Applications'.
3. Choose which program you want to disable.
4. hit like to this answer if it works.